# How to set up SQL Server Auditing with blob storage in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-sql-server

I'm trying to update my SQL Server ARM template to use blob storage instead of table storage.  What I have doesn't fail entries appear in the blob storage account but it doesn't update the Azure portal.  Has anyone else experienced this?

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "type": "auditingSettings",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "name": "Default",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('serverName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "State": "Enabled",
        "storageEndpoint": "[variables('storageEndpointName')]",
        "storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]",
        "retentionDays": "90",
        "auditActionsAndGroups": null,
        "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
        "isStorageSecondaryKeyInUse": false
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I have doesn't fail entries appear in the blob storage account
>   but it doesn't update the Azure portal.

Do you mean you mean you have update SQL to enable auditing, but you can't find the change on Azure portal?

If I understand it correctly, maybe we should check the status of Azure SQL Auditing with PowerShell script:

```
PS C:\Users> Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditingPolicy -ServerName jasontest321 -ResourceGroupName vm -DatabaseName jason


DatabaseName       : jason
AuditAction        : {}
AuditActionGroup   : {SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP, FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP, BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP}
ResourceGroupName  : vm
ServerName         : jasontest321
AuditType          : Blob
AuditState         : Enabled
StorageAccountName : 531777eastus
StorageKeyType     : Primary
RetentionInDays    : 0
```

More information about use ARM template turning on blob auditing, please refer to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqlemea/2017/01/11/arm-template-turning-on-blob-auditing/).

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.